# Values in a HashMap being overriden by the newest value (Java)

Tags: java, reference, hashmap

```
Map<Integer, Configuration> m

Configuration {
    int configNumber;
    Map<Integer, Pair<Set<Address>, Set<Integer>>> groupInfo;
}
```

My map m essentially maps the configNumber to Configuration class. Future configNumber requires information from previous configNumber's values. However, when I add a new configNumber into my map, the second `Set<Integer>>` follows with the `Set<Integer>>` of the newly put configNumber. For example:

Initial:

- Key: `0`, Value: `Configuration(configNum=0, groupInfo={1=([server3, server2, server1],[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])})`

When I add a new Key, say 1:

- Key: `0`, Value: `Configuration(configNum=0, groupInfo={1=([server3, server2, server1],[6, 7, 8, 9, 10])})`
- Key: `1`, Value: `Configuration(configNum=1, groupInfo={1=([server3, server2, server1],[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]), 2=([server6, server5, server4],[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])})`

As you can see, key `0`'s right `Set<Integer>` in the pair changes with what was recently put. I thought that this was a problem of reference. But every time I created a `new HashMap<>()` and put all the values there before accessing it. Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide the code that calls the `put()` method of the map?

Comment: "`Map<Integer, Pair<Set<Address>, Set<Integer>>>`" This type signature is pretty grim. You should consider creating a specific class to use instead of the `Pair`.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious cause would be re-using the `Set<Integer>` or the `Pair<>` from the first entry when constructing the second one.  But without your code, we can't tell.

This is one reason I advocate for copy-on-write in public APIs; if someone you don't know is providing you with a collection, make your own copy before storing it.  (If you ever start getting `ConcurrentModificationException`s you know you need to start doing this.)